# Python: regex for list of phrases containing question marks. list of phrases is in a .csv

Tags: python-3.x, regex, csv

I have a master corpus containing thousands of popular novels.  I then have a .csv file that's a list containing about 450 different phrases (rhetorical_devices.csv).  I am trying to use regex to do two things with these data:

1. Return a boolean telling me whether or not any phrase from the .csv list is present in the master_corpus.
2. Search for and then count the number exact match phrases between the .csv list and the master_corpus.  I don't need to know which phrases matched, just the number of matches.

The .csv list is almost all multi-word phrases, things like:

- huffed loudly
- felt light-headed
- couldn't they?
- stop!

Some of the phrases contain pieces of punctuation that are relevant to my search, so for example, I need to be able to ID "couldn't they?" with the words in that exact order, question mark included.  I keep getting all sorts of hits on sentences that contain "couldn't" and "they" and "?" in any random order.  For this example, "They couldn't just stop?" is returning 2 hits for the count.  Seems like my code is just looking for all of the words rather than them in the correct order and containing stipulated punctuation.

Right now, this is my attempt at a boolean, where master_corpus is all of the novels:

```
        phrase_list = self.corpora['rhetorical_devices.csv'][0].to_list()
        phrase_list = [i.lower() for i in phrase_list]
        regex = '|'.join(phrase_list)
        return bool(re.search(regex, master_corpus.lower()))
```

I think the ! and ? from the list are ending up as regex operators, but also I'm not sure how to import the list and make sure I'm looking for those exact matches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that the items in "regex" have the phrases separated by that token rather than the individual words?

If the boolean is important, you can also skip the regex and do something like,

`if "couldn't they" in corpus...` to just check for the phrases' presence

Comment: @Mike L I'm not sure how to do the first bit (verify items in "regex" have the phrases separated by |...

As for the second suggestion, since there are about 450 different phrases in rhertorical_devices.csv, I don't want to write 'if' statements for each of them.

Comment: 1) print out the regex pattern
2) you wouldnt do them individually, it was an example. You can loop over the phrases and check them that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regex, you should loop over the phrases like Mike L suggested:

```py
total_matches = 0

corpus = master_corpus.lower()

for phrase in phrase_list:
    total_matches += corpus.count(phrase)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dash.  Just to be sure I'm tracking, you're saying I should: <br/>
```
    phrase_list = self.corpora['rhetorical_devices.csv'][0].to_list() <br/>
    phrase_list = [i.lower() for i in phrase_list] <br/>
    total_matches = 0 <br/>
    corpus = master_corpus.lower() <br/>
    for phrase in phrase_list: <br/>
        total_matches += corpus.count(phrase)
```